# Excel: Run-Time Error '13' Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

What could be the reason, that I get 
the the  Run-Time Error '13' Type Mismatch
with this line of VBA Code:

```
.Cells(1, 1) = CDate(Format(Now, "dd.mm.yy hh:mm"))
```

The problem is, that a colleague doesn't get this error. We have both a "German" office.

Comment: just a word of warning on the code any how, you are reusing mm where for month you need mm and minutes nn.

Comment: Did you try "dd/mm/yy" just in case?

Comment: it will work up until 10:13 I expect where you will see the wrong time.

Comment: @Elmex Have a look at your control panel and see what your Regional & Language settings are set to, I think you will find that you are not using German there.

Comment: @Mike Miller: I thought that too, but I was testing at 9:53! I think that in newer versions of Office they've handled it based on the context (ie `msgbox format(now,"dd.mm.yy hh:mm")` at 9:53 this morning did return "15.06.11 09:53". I'm positive this wouldn't work in VB6 though, so maybe its a tweak to recent VBA.

Comment: @jon thanks for the tip, nice change really.

Comment: @Elmex: You do realize that you are taking a type `Date` (`Now`), converting it to type `String` using `Format`, and converting it back to type `Date` using `CDate`? Any particular reason you want to do this seemingly useless back-and-forth?

Comment: Just to clarify: VBA can figure out `mm` means minutes if `mm` is immediately preceded by `hh`. Still, `nn` is much better practice as it it unambiguous.

Comment: @Remou: Thank you. Your hint was helpful. On the one hand, I used "German", but on the other hand the date-format was yyyy-mm-dd. I don't know why.  Now I have changed it --> the runtime error has been disappeared.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need the format, since its just being turned straight back into a Date before you fill the cell.

You should really either have:

```
.Cells(1, 1) = Format(Now,"dd.mm.yy hh:mm")
```

or even better

```
.Cells(1, 1) = Now
```

then format the column as follows:

```
Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yy hh:mm"
```

Note: Its possible that having the mm in the format string could not help, although having just tried it out it seems to work ok.